# How do I change button color on press in bootstrap?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'd like to declare a different button color in Bootstrap when someone presses that button. How can I achieve that? This is the code of my current button:

```
.comment-box .btn {
    background-color: rgb(38, 173, 228);
    color: white;
}
```

(P.S.: Does anybody know what css-lib stackoverflow is using for it's blue buttons?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you want to use the `:active` selector:

```
 .comment-box .btn:active {
            background-color: rgb(38, 173, 228);
            color: white;
        }
```

Here is a refrence for other selectors:

```
/* unvisited link */
    a:link {
        color: green;
    }

    /* visited link */
    a:visited {
        color: green;
    }

    /* mouse over link */
    a:hover {
        color: red;
    }

    /* selected link */
    a:active {
        color: yellow;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can keep count of the button click by using `onclick` using javascript and then on every click, change its color, which you can define in an array. 
The index of the color in array will correspond to the number of times a button is clicked.